# how to view the data base name of a sql report in microstrategy

Tags: reporting, microstrategy

Can any one help me in this?
how to view the database name of a sql report in microstrategy?

Answer (score 2):

On MicroStrategy Desktop, when you right click on a report and choose "View SQL", you'll see something like:

```
DB User:        db_user_xxx
DB Instance:    db_instance_xxx
```

If you then go to Administration > Configuration Managers > Database Instances you can view the database instance mentioned on the report.

Editing that object will allow you to view which ODBC connection that database instance is using.

Then you just need to have a look at the ODBC definition on your Intelligence Server machine to get additional details.